# What would it look like if time is stopped

Tags: science-based, time

Say a person can either move faster than light/ as fast as light without changing his position relative to other people (or any other manner of stopping time for that matter): What would he see? Would the world be distorted? Would it look normal? What if he moved?

Extra: What if even light itself is frozen in time? How would that be perceived?

Edit: since the question about "being able to see when time is stopped" has already been answered, what if time is not stopped, but a person perceives things as if he is moving as fast as/faster than light (without changing his relative position, as described above)

Comment: [Will a person be able to see when he stops time?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56591/will-a-person-be-able-to-see-when-he-stops-time) seems to be highly relevant for you. Could you try to differentiate your question from that one? Otherwise this looks like a duplicate. Welcome to WorldBuilding by the way. If you got questions please take the tour and visit the help center. You can edit your question with the little edit button if you want.

Comment: [This](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57925/stopping-time-by-speeding-it-up-inside-a-bubble?rq=1) one might help you, too.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"perceives things as if he is moving ... faster than light without changing his relative position"*  If you're not actually moving at all (let alone faster than light), how do you perceive things as if you are?  Your eyes operate by receiving rays of light (as discussed in the answer below) so no mental ability for altered perception is going to make those rays of light hit your eyes faster than they normally do

Comment: Moving as fast as *anything, really*, without changing position, is an oxymoron. Asking for such thing without explanation seems useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You wouldn't see anything at all.**

The reason you can *see* is because rays of light are being captured by your eyes. If time ***stops***, then light ***also stops***, meaning that your eyes have nothing left to capture.

Comment: so would it be like total darkness? just black?

Comment: @rowanjuinen - yes, I would imagine that's exactly what it would be like. That being said, some people might imagine this differently. It can't happen as far as we're aware, so who really knows?